# Static Website, File Upload and recaptcha

Tags: forms, nuxt.js, recaptcha

I am just thinking what the best approach is to implement a simple form with file upload on a static website without any backend.

**Scenario:**

I have static website (NuxtJS) where a form can be filled and files can be uploaded.
To protect this form I wanted to use [recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) by Google but as I read a little further in their documentation it seems that I need a backend which is a overkill for a static website.
Furthermore I wanted to support file upload... quite complicated without a backend.

**What I thought of:**

Maybe an existing product which does exactly what I am looking for? Or should I build a AWS Lambda Pipeline (of course with an S3 Bucket) to function as my "backend" for recaptcha and file upload.
Is there any approach which makes this scenario simpler, or am I thinking to complicated at the moment.

Use Case / Flow Chart:

1. Users enters Website.
2. Fills out form.
3. (optional) uploads files
4. Checks recaptcha
5. *Clicks Send* - Sends "Message" in our companies slack channel / or email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However I solved this "common" task with a custom "backend" hosted on AWS Lambda which makes the whole stuff "serverless".

For those who are interested in "how to setup a server less backend" here's the current flow-chart which I made use of.

[image]

As you can see after the recaptcha is validated on client side and a token is generated, it is sent to the AWS API Gateway which triggers a Lambda Function (NodeJS Implementation of a Backend) where the token is validated and for file uploads pre-signed Uris are generated.
*Notice: The API Gateway and the S3 Bucket need a valid CORS Configuration to communicate with each other and the world.*

Comment: Beautiful @Markus, any chance you have a repo to share of this setup to study?

Comment: The setup / code is currently in an internal repo. Maybe I can write an article about this in a few days.

Comment: That would be awesome please let me know if you do that Markus!